# RaspberryPi - error when trying to reference a user directory on boot service?

Tags: bash, service, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, systemctl

I am trying to reference a user directory on boot for my raspberry pi 4 32 bit bullseye desktop with a service setup on `systemctl`. This service maps my ip address to an .env file. The process is as follows:

1. `setup.service` attempts to create a .env file using `setup.sh` with my current ip address
2. `setup.timer` fires off the service 1 minute after boot

This works flawlessly when my `setup.sh` looks like this:

```
...
destdir=/home/me/my_directory/.env
echo "REACT_APP_MACHINE_HOST_IP=$REACT_APP_MACHINE_HOST_IP" > "$destdir"
```

But when I try to replace the value of "me" with the machine user in order to make this more transferrable I get this error on boot:

```
...
destdir=/home/"$USER"/my_directory/.env
echo "REACT_APP_MACHINE_HOST_IP=$REACT_APP_MACHINE_HOST_IP" > "$destdir"

/home//my_directory/.env does not exist...
```

Not sure where I'm off because I made a quick test.sh script and the following echoed the directory correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash

mydir=/home/"$USER"/my_directory/
echo $mydir
```

It seems like no user is recognized. I am assuming this has something to do with system running on root? Or is my syntax off?

EDIT:

My `setup.service` below:

```
[Unit]
Description=setup mcw
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/setup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And what I run to automate aka `automate.sh`:

```
# copy ip file to task and authorize
sudo cp /home/${USER}/my_directory/setup.sh /usr/local/bin/setup.sh
sudo chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/setup.sh

# create setup files
sudo cp /home/${USER}/my_directory/setup.service /etc/systemd/system/setup.service
sudo cp /home/${USER}/my_directory/setup.timer /etc/systemd/system/setup.timer

# add permissions for the service
sudo chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/setup.service

# setup and reload systemctl
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable setup.timer
sudo systemctl start setup.timer
```

Comment: 2 hints, you are running it with a shell, not a login shell so `$USER` would not be set, and secondly, does the service mention anything about running it as a particular user? In other words, where exactly do you expect `$USER` to be set?

Comment: Ahh this makes sense. At the moment the service is not setup with a user in mind. So perhaps that would be the key. I edited my answer above so you can see what service looks like perhaps you might have some tips. Thank you.